# Background-color within 'div' not working

Tags: html, css

Attempting to color the background of a div containing images, I only succeed if I encapsulate the footer in the div which I do not want. I only want the background-color to apply to the section within the div.

```css
/* CSS */

    div#gallery_contain {
       width: 850px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 0 5%;
       background-color: #1a75ff;
    }

      footer {
       clear: both;
       text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="gallery_contain">
        <section>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: The div needs a height, or content with height, or it isn't going to show.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `have some content in your div`, or `specify height explicitly` in your css for the div to show with the background.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no height on your gallery container the background will not show. If you set a height on the DIV, or add content to the DIV, the background-color will show.

```
div#gallery_contain {
   width: 850px;
   min-height: 100px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 5%;
   background-color: #1a75ff;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
```

OR

```
<div id="gallery_contain">
    <section>
         This is the gallery.
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `display:block;`. Or you can apply this `height:auto; width:auto;` when there is some content in there.